# WIndows file/ folder permission using vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, file, permissions

I can set file/ folder restriction using the given code.

```
Imports System.Security.AccessControl

Dim FolderPath As String = "C:\TestingFolder" 'Specify the folder here
Dim UserAccount As String = "MYDOMAIN\someuser" 'Specify the user here

Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
FolderAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection(True, False) 'uncomment to remove existing permissions
FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

My aim is to set the permission using the code in a way that only my application can change the read/write access to the file/folder. No one can change the permission except my vb.net program.
My goal is to write a security application which will ask password to access the program, and the program will be able to grant access(read/write/modify) to the user.

Comment: Access rules are user-account based.  So you will have to impersonate another user account.

Comment: Can u pls clarify it more?