# How to block access to any file or exe vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, antivirus

How do I block and unblock a file or executable from being opened permanently during run time in vb.net?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893232/windows-file-folder-permission-using-vb-net

Comment: what if i dont know the users account name its for a antivirus quarantine

Comment: AFAIK An Anti-Virus quarantine is usually just an encrypted database where they store the file's name, its contents (bytes) and its metadata, but the actual file is deleted from disk. When you choose to restore the file the AV software creates a new file with the original name and writes the contents from the database to the file.

Comment: if i compressed the file would it quarantine the file too?

Comment: Compressing it is one way to make the file un-runnable, because you modify its contents so that the OS cannot read it as it normally would. However this approach isn't really safe in terms of security as one can easily find out how you compress it and then decompress it again. Though if you are only looking to prevent users from running it directly by double-clicking it, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code, and you can use `Environment.UserName` to get the name of the user, and this is will lock any type of file and it will lock folder too :

```
Dim FSS As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(Application.StartupPath & "\quarantine\" & NewTextDoc.Text)
FSS.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))
File.SetAccessControl(Application.StartupPath & "\quarantine\" & NewTextDoc.Text, FSS)
```

**And to unlock the file/folder just remove the `AccessRule` like this :**

```
Dim FSS As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(Application.StartupPath & "\quarantine\" & NewTextDoc.Text)
FSS.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))
File.SetAccessControl(Application.StartupPath & "\quarantine\" & NewTextDoc.Text, FSS)
```

**Finally Hope this will help you :)**

Comment: @BrandonWilliams , You'er welcome :), please accept the answer if it really helped you so it can help others.

Comment: ok i will how do i do that ( sorry im new here) but can i have quick help when i put the path in (FilePath/FolderPath) i get blue line underneath it

Comment: @BrandonWilliams , Oh sorry, yes, you need to add the `FSS` variable in the last lines, i edited my answer, check it again.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams , Thanks, did you see the edit though?

Comment: dude under "File/FolderPath" how could i add Application.StartupPath & "\quarantine\" and after quarantine i want to grab text from a label (NewTextDoc) is label, would this work Application.StartupPath & "\quarantine\(Label1.text)" so it locks startup path folder quarantine and file from label?

Comment: @BrandonWilliams ,  I edited my answer again, you can check it again, hope it helped.

Comment: thanks so where NewTextDoc.Text is i put Label1.Text yeah? but dude your well helpful cheers

Comment: @BrandonWilliams : Be aware that this code only restricts access for _**the current user**_. All other users will still have access to it and also the system itself, meaning the file can still be executed either by another user/administrator or by the system. If you want to make a "quarantine" the _**very least**_ thing you should do is to modify the file's contents to make it un-runnable.