# Prevent file from being (Deleted/Edited) in Runtime VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, api-hook

is that possible to protect a file inside project directory location.

for example (test.txt or test.bat or ... Etc).

i have important data dont wanna change inside txt, while runing the project.

tired many thing's.

- lock file by permission / file stream (but not work good, it easy to unlock by change user's permission.

> now my code i tried but it lock only the project not the file, in runtime
>
> let's say my file type (test.txt or test.bat or ... Etc).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Class c_AntiKill
<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Shared Function GetKernelObjectSecurity(Handle As IntPtr, securityInformation As Integer, <Out> pSecurityDescriptor As Byte(), nLength As UInteger, ByRef lpnLengthNeeded As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Shared Function SetKernelObjectSecurity(Handle As IntPtr, securityInformation As Integer, <[In]> pSecurityDescriptor As Byte()) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetCurrentProcess() As IntPtr
End Function
Protected Function GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(processHandle As IntPtr) As RawSecurityDescriptor
    Dim psd() As Byte = New Byte(1) {}
    Dim bufSizeNeeded As UInteger
    GetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, &H4, psd, 0, bufSizeNeeded)
    psd = New Byte(bufSizeNeeded) {}
    If bufSizeNeeded < 0 OrElse bufSizeNeeded > Short.MaxValue Then
        Throw New Win32Exception()
    End If
    If Not GetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, &H4, psd, bufSizeNeeded, bufSizeNeeded) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception()
    End If
    Return New RawSecurityDescriptor(psd, 0)
End Function
Protected Sub SetProcessSecurityDescriptor(processHandle As IntPtr, dacl As RawSecurityDescriptor)
    Dim rawsd As Byte() = New Byte(dacl.BinaryLength - 1) {}
    dacl.GetBinaryForm(rawsd, 0)
    If Not SetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, &H4, rawsd) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub c_ImAntiKill()
    Dim hProcess As IntPtr = GetCurrentProcess()
    Dim dacl = GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(hProcess)
    dacl.DiscretionaryAcl.InsertAce(0, New CommonAce(AceFlags.None, AceQualifier.AccessDenied, CInt(&HF0000 Or &H100000 Or &HFFF), New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing), False, Nothing))
    SetProcessSecurityDescriptor(hProcess, dacl)
    '   Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use user's permission.
answer from another thread.(work good)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45785316